# Issue with nested if

Tags: vba, nested-if

Please can anyone point what wrong I am doing in the code given below, I am getting compilation error that for every EndIF there has to be corresponding IF THanks in advance:

```
Public Function customavg(rng As Range, nr_weeks As Integer)
Dim total As Integer, count_rng_row As Integer, count_wk As Integer, counter_rng As Integer

total = 0
count_rng_row = rng.Rows.count
count_wk = 0
counter_rng = count_rng_row


   For counter_rng = count_rng_row To 1
     If count_wk < nr_weeks Then
        If rng.Cells.Offset(0, -1) = "b" Then total = total + rng.Cells.Value
           counter_rng = counter_rng - 1
           count_wk = count_wk + 1
        End If
     'Else
      '     counter_rng = counter_rng - 0
       '    count_wk = count_wk + 0
     End If
   Next counter_rng

customavg = total / nr_weeks

End Function
```

Answer (score 6):

The culprit is

```
If rng.Cells.Offset(0, -1) = "b" Then total = total + rng.Cells.Value
```

The syntax of `If` is either

```
If <cond> Then <command>
```

OR

```
If <cond> Then
   <commands>
End If
```

Comment: Correct. You just have to put `total = total + rng.Cells.Value` on a new line.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. I have one more doubt.. Can a loop be run in a decreasing order, for example in my code above.. "For counter_rng = count_rng_row To 1" as I need to take the most recent values for the summation, so the counter will go from bottom cell in the range to the top.

Comment: That is an absolutely different question but here you are: `For c  = 9 To 1 Step -1` .